# Detecting when a user clicks outside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm showing the user a modal/lightbox. The modal shows up and the rest of the page goes dim when the user clicks a button. Usual stuff.

However I want to do this. If the user clicks any element outside of the modal, I want the modal to go away and the page to return to normal.

How can this be done? I know I can set an onclick event for body, and then check if event target is my modal, but what if the user clicks on a link/textbox/button within the modal? In that case, target won't be the modal. How can I solve this?

Is there a way to check if the event target is contained with `<div id="modal"></div>`, so if it is, I won't close the modal, and if not, that means user clicked outside the modal and I can close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a div under the modal that fills the entire space and attach your click handler to it.

Comment: I'd go with @roXon 's solution. It's a better implementation if you ever need to change your html

Comment: This is just a work around (or a nice feature, but depends). It will imply additional code to create a full-sized element, and additionally it will block any interaction with other (outside the modal) document elements nulling the click. So if you don't plan to put an **opaque** (visible) full-layer - in the terms of User experience this is something to avoid.

Comment: I disagree, I've put a layer behind it which dims out the rest of the page, and you click it to have the modal closed and the rest of the page restored, its quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/amudim/2/edit)**

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
   if(e.target.id !== 'modal' ){
     $('#modal').hide();
   }
});

$('#modal').mouseup(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();  // prevent mouseup propagate to underneath layers
});
```

Comment: This looks way better than my answer :)

Comment: @Arnaud edited my answer with ha demo :) now it's even better :) thx!

Comment: @IMos you have to try again as I modified a bit the code and changed the demo :)

Comment: I don't want the modal to just be closed on mouseover, I want it to be done on clicking. Also, will this work for elements inside #modal if they are clicked (so it will stay open)?

Comment: @ClickUpvote nobody is hiding it on mouseover, where did you read that? No, if you click your Modal's inner elements - it will stay there, as you can clearly see in the demo!

Comment: @IMos this will on every click inside the document iterate a click handler through the WHOLE DOM structure searching for a `closest` modal. surely not the best way to do it :D

Comment: @IMos while my demo - on click detects immediately the targeted element for it's our `#modal`. Hope you understand now why I like to write useful, fast and unobtrusive code.

Comment: This quite a nice solution, I've been going round implementing this the wrong round in my projects :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").click(function(e){
    if( ! $(e.target).closest("#modal").length ){
        $('#modal').hide();
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/amudim/7/edit)

Comment: So, on every click on the page (with closed Modal) this code will headlessly run up the dom tree searching for a `.closest()` element... IMHO: bad.

Comment: @roXon Yes but it works as it should. The same approach used in [jQuery UI Dialog](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L682)

Answer (score 1):

Another one approach:

```
var mouseOverModal = false;

$(document).click(function(e){
   if ( ! mouseOverModal ){
       // close modal
   }
});

$('#modal').bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
     mouseOverModal = ( "mouseenter" == e.type );
})

$('#open-modal-handler').click(function(){  
    // open modal  
    return false; // <- IMPORTANT
})
```