# close modal when click outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal box which has a couple buttons inside. On click outside I want that modal close. I've added ref to the parent element and it's works fine, everything closing  when you click outside. But if you click on that buttons inside this modal box , it closes too. How to detect child elements inside this ref and do not allow close modal box?

[image]

```
public handleClickoutside() {
this.props.showMessage()
}

public handleClick = (e) => {
if (this.DOMArrowBox.current !== e.target) {
  this.handleClickoutside()
}
}

public componentWillMount() {
document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false)
}

public componentWillUnmount() {
document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false)
}

<div className={this.props.className} ref={this.DOMArrowBox}>
    <Social />
    <CallMe className="arrow__box-button" open={this.props.open} />
    <Close
      className="arrow-button_close"
      onClick={this.props.showMessage}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: instead this.DOMArrowBox.current !== e.target , try this  this.DOMArrowBox.contains(e.target) once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another)

Comment: You may Roko's answer helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291093/detecting-when-a-user-clicks-outside-a-div?rq=1#answer-14291108

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ref on the Button inside modal too and check if the target element is contained within that or not

```
    public handleClickoutside() {
       this.props.showMessage()
    }

    public handleClick = (e) => {

        if (!this.DOMArrowBox.current.contains(e.target) && !ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.btnRef.current).contains(e.target)) {
          this.handleClickoutside()
        }

    }

    public componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false)
    }

    public componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false)
    }

    <div className={this.props.className} ref={this.DOMArrowBox}>
        <Social />
        <CallMe className="arrow__box-button" ref={this.btnRef}open={this.props.open} />
        <Close
          className="arrow-button_close"
          onClick={this.props.showMessage}
        />
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to resolve this, is to revert the issue :
let's imagine that **you're not catching the click outside your modal, but the click on the modal background wrapper**.

You should wrap your `<Modal>` into a invisible `<Wrapper>`, with a lesser z-index than the modal, and with the following styles, to take the parent element/window full width & height :

```
.modal-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1; // has to be < of Modal's z-index
    width: 100%; // or 100vw
    height: 100%; // or 100vh
}
```

Then, attach the `ref` on the `<Wrapper>` and in your `handleClick` method, replace `!==` by `===` (because, remember, we reverted the problem).

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onBlur` event to handle clickoutside. Please, have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549294/reactjs-dropdown-menu-close-other-menus-before-opening-current/54549604#54549604) with working example.